# Logstash plugin to import mysql data gives manti core error

Tags: mysql, jdbc, elasticsearch, logstash

I have elasticsearch 2.2.0 and logstash 2.1 installed on my centos 7 instance.

Have following in my logstash abc.conf file:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.2.0.0/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xx:3306/mysql"
    jdbc_user => "xxxx"
    jdbc_password => "blahblah"
    parameters => { "status" => "published" }
    #schedule => "0 * * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT field1, field2 from tbl_orders where status = :status"
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "abc"
        document_type => "tbl_orders"
        document_id => "%{field1}"
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
```

When i run this file to import the mysql data, i get following error:

```
Connection refused {:class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}
Logstash startup completed
Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at '["http://localhost:9200/"]', but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down!
```

I checked the connection to elasticsearch before running this file and it came fine. Where am i going wrong. Any suggestions?

Installed logsttash with following commands:

```
rpm --import https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch

Add logstash.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/

[logstash-2.1]
name=Logstash repository for 2.1.x packages
baseurl=http://packages.elastic.co/logstash/2.1/centos
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=1

yum install logstash
```

Will the manti core issue  `Upgrading plugins with manticore throws an error and sometimes corrupts installation #4818` still affect?

Comment: You might be hitting the Manticore issue mentioned in a [recent blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-lines-2016-03-21). Can you check if the latest `elasticsearch` output version (2.5.3)  works for you?

Comment: Have added my logstash installation steps. Please check and suggest

Comment: Will the bin/plugin install --version 2.5.3 logstash-output-elasticsearch also fix #4818. It is not clear from the blog page.